# setting value for input(submit) button

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

Guys I'm new to JavaScript, so not sure where the error is. Basically I've two submit buttons in my cshtml. one with the id = email and other id = sms. I've set value=" ". I'm using these buttons in a form.

what I want to do is; by clicking on these button I want to pass them a value so that I can use that value in model and controller, like in switch statement. tried various ways but still its passing null value. please advise!

```
function GetVal() {
    var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        if (input[i].type == 'submit') {
            if (input[i].id == 'email') {
                //input[i].value = 'submitEmail';
                //input[i].setAttribute("value", "subEmail");
                document.getElementById("email").setAttribute("subEmail", "value");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

<input id="email" type="submit" class="@( Model.UnsubscribedEmail == null ? "unsubscribe" : "subscribe")" onclick="GetVal();" />
```

**Model**

```
public static void susbscription(MyModel model, string submitButton)
    {
     switch (submitButton)
        {
            case "subEmail":
            //Code here
            break;
         }
     }
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MarketingPreferences(MyModel model, string submitButton)
    {
        MarketingPreferencesModel.susbscription(model, submitButton);

        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: `input[i].value = 'submitEmail'` should work, are you sure its finding the right element?

Comment: yeah. i've used alert to display the element and it was right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<input id="email" type="submit" name="submitButton" onclick="GetVal(this);" class="@( Model.UnsubscribedEmail == null ? "unsubscribe" : "subscribe")"  />
```

In JavaScript:

```
function GetVal(element) {
    element.value = "subEmail";
}
```

In Action:

```
public ActionResult MarketingPreferences(MyModel model, string submitButton)
{
    MarketingPreferencesModel.susbscription(model, submitButton);

    return View(model);
}
```